# Minimize typing to convert mp4 to mp3

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to minimize the typing needed to convert a mp4 to a mp3.

This is what I have been doing:

```bsh
ffmpeg -i 'Borrowed Angel.mp4' -vn -acodec libmp3lame -ac 2 -ab 160k -ar 48000 'Borrowed Angel.mp3'
```

This is what I have so far:

```bsh
ffmpeg -i $1.mp4 -vn -acodec libmp3lame -ac 2 -ab 160k -ar 48000 $1.mp3
```

I think I need a macro.

But it needs an output file.

Comment: Write that into a file , make it executable via ```chmod +x``` , add the address of that into your **$PATH** environment variable (add it to the ~/.bashrc file) ,and execute it in terminal via the name you've given to that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a script or program to help you with this.  You'll want to create a directory `~/.bin` or `~/.scripts`, and add it to your `$PATH` Environment Variable.  You can do this by editing and saving the following line within `~/.bashrc`, towards the end, but exact location isn't key here:

```
export PATH=$HOME/.bin:$PATH
```

Now any file within `~/.bin/` with `+x` (executable) access can be run after sourcing the new `~/.bashrc` file (ie: in a new terminal).

```bsh
touch ~/.bin/mov-dac
chmod +x ~/.bin/mov-dac
```

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

MOV="$*"
FILENAME=$(basename "${MOV// /_}" | sed 's/\(.*\)-.*/\1/').mp3
ffmpeg -i "${MOV}" -vn -acodec libmp3lame -ac 2 -ab 160k -ar 48000 /tmp/"${FILENAME}"
```

Then, in new terminals, you can run `mov-dac /path/to/My\ File.mp4` and you'll get `/tmp/My_File.mp3`

I prefer to keep the audio as-is, but strip it from the video file and save within that filetype/container.  In additional, any track more than 15m (900s) long is added to the "Sets" album, instead of "Singles", for easier sorting.  `$OUTDIR` is the final destination and has `_Sets/` and `_Singles/` within.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# @earthmeLon

MOV="$*"
OUTDIR="/mnt/DAC"
MEDIAINFO=$(mediainfo "${MOV}" --Output=JSON)
FORMAT=$(echo $MEDIAINFO | jq '.[]| .track[] | select(."@type"=="Audio")| .Format' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
FORMAT=$(echo $FORMAT | tr -d '"')
if [ $FORMAT == "vorbis" ]; then
    FORMAT="ogg"
fi
DURATION=$(echo $MEDIAINFO | jq '.[]| .track[] | select(."@type"=="Audio")| .Duration')
DURATION=$(echo $DURATION | tr -d '"')
DURATION=${DURATION%.*}
if [ $DURATION -gt 900 ]; then
    ALBUM="Sets"
else
    ALBUM="Singles"
fi

FILENAME=$(basename "${MOV// /_}" | sed 's/\(.*\)-.*/\1/').${FORMAT}
ffmpeg -y -i "$MOV" -vn -metadata album=$ALBUM -acodec copy /tmp/"${FILENAME}"
if [ -d ${OUTDIR}/_${ALBUM} ]; then
    cp /tmp/"${FILENAME}" ${OUTDIR}/_${ALBUM}/
    rm /tmp/"${FILENAME}"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks. Works great. :-)

Comment: `~/bin` is already listed in `~/.profile`, so no need to edit `~/.bashrc` or mess with `$PATH`. However, once `~/bin` is created you'll either have to run `source ~/.profile`, or simply log out and log in for it to get recognized.

Answer (score 0):

You can write it into a file , say `mp423`(mp4 to mp3 converter) and save it into a specific folder ( I personally use `~/.scripts`) and then you have to add that path to the **$PATH** environment variable to be able to execute it directly in the terminal without mentioning the full path.So add this to your `~/.bashrc` file :

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/yourusername/.scripts/
```

And then you can run that this way :

```
mp423 "Borrowed Angel"
```

Don't forget to use the **Double quotes** if the name contains **space** because the bash will interpret that as two separate arguments.

Best regards :)

Comment: Package manager does not have mp423. @Parsa Mousavi

Comment: This is the name of your script.Could be anything else.That was just an example. Why is the repository supposed to have **mp423**?